# how to get rest URL in Magento2

Tags: magento2, url, rest-api

I need to get a link of this kind`http://localhost/Magento2/rest`
I have a code by which I get base_url:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$baseUrl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl
```

So i get `http://localhost/Magento2/`,but i need `http://localhost/Magento2/rest`.Help find a solution, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is available programmatically, but you can manually append 'index.php/rest/V1/' to the base URL as this should not ever change.

Answer (score 1):

This one would work for my case.

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Url $url */
$url = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Url::class);

$url->getUrl(
null,
[
    '_path' => 'enquiry',
    '_secure' => true,
    '_direct' => 'rest/V1/link-to-resource',
    '_query' => [
        'paramA' => "XXXX",
        'paramB' => "XXXXX"
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try with Below solution:**

```
/**
* @urlBuilder \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
*/

$urlBuilder->getUrl("rest/*/V1/");
```