# How to stop create customer via rest API in magento 2?

Tags: rest-api, webapi, magento2.4.0

I do not know how to stop to create customers via REST API in magento 2. I have magento 2 instance in 2.4.0 version

I found a below code in `vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/webapi.xml` path

```
<route url="/V1/customers" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface" method="createAccount"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
```

Above code to create customer via rest api, how can I disable this flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would utilize Plugin in this case.

Specifically, create a `di.xml` file in your `Vendor_Module/etc/rest` directory, declare a plugin for the service class which provides Customer create function.

```
<config>
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface">
      <plugin name="your_plugin_name" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\AccountManagementPlugin" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Then we're using the `around` method to stop the `createAccount` function from executing at all by not calling `$proceed()`.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;

class AccountManagementPlugin
{
    public function aroundSave(
        AccountManagementInterface $subject,
        callable $proceed,
        CustomerInterface $customer,
        $password = null,
        $redirectUrl = ''
    ) {
        // DO NOT call $proceed() at all!
        
        // Other than that you can throw an exception telling that this action is not permitted or so
        // Or do nothing at all, that's fine.
    }
}
```

One side effect is, any other function that used to/is supposed to call to this `createAccount` function will not be able to call it at all. If this is not what you would expect, then a fix would be, you can check for the requested URL, if URL is something other than `rest/V1/customers`, meaning it is calling to a different endpoint, then proceed as usual (by calling `$proceed()`).

[Reference on how to get requested API URL.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/285014/how-to-get-rest-url-in-magento2)

Hopefully it works for you!

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you, I used plugin before for createAccount method and checking url come from API or from create account form